# Unmarshalling XML/JSON to class in Apache Karavan

Tags: java, apache-camel, unmarshalling

I am new in programming in Apache Karavan and i am encountering a problem with unmarshalling. I created User.java class and I would like to map the attributes from ${body} context to a java class I created.

User.java

```
package com.dhls.camel;

public class User {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public User(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My yaml file

```
- route:
    id: route-6819
    from:
      uri: timer:timer
      id: from-ee72
      steps:
        - setBody:
            id: setBody-5057
            expression:
              simple:
                expression: |-
                  <user>
                  <name>John</name>
                  <surname>Smith</surname>
                  </user>
                id: simple-e9cc
        - unmarshal:
            id: unmarshal-a939
            json:
              id: json-9671
              unmarshalType: User
```

And this is an error i am getting.

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: java.lang.Class
        at org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeCamelException(RuntimeCamelException.java:51)
        at org.apache.camel.support.component.PropertyConfigurerSupport.property(PropertyConfigurerSupport.java:97)
lass
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:206)
        at org.apache.camel.support.component.PropertyConfigurerSupport.property(PropertyConfigurerSupport.java:95)
        ... 41 more
```

Is there any easy way to map the attributes to class using unmarshal component and then use whole class in the following components?

Comment: The User class need a default no-arg constructor for the mapping to be possible via the setters

Answer (score 0):

1. In setBody you set XML but then you use unmarshal Data Format JSON. T make it work you need to transform XML to JSON first.
2. In XML closing tag is not  but
3. Unmarshal requires default constructor in Java class
4. Karavan uses plain folder structure so no package required in the class

Try
User.java

```
public class User {
private String name;
private String surname;

public User() {
 
}

public User(String name, String surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

route.camel.yaml:

```
- route:
id: route-6819
from:
  uri: timer:timer
  id: from-ee72
  steps:
    - setBody:
        id: setBody-5057
        expression:
          simple:
            expression: |-
              <user>
              <name>John</name>
              <surname>Smith</surname>
              </user>
            id: simple-e9cc
    - to:
        uri: kamelet:xj-identity-action
        id: to-1e55
        parameters:
          direction: XML2JSON
    - unmarshal:
        id: unmarshal-a939
        json:
          id: json-9671
          unmarshalType: User
```